# Clojure: convert vector of maps into map of maps with incremented keys

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of maps

`cards_vector = [{...} {...} ...]`

and an atom

`(def cards_map (atom {})`

For each map in `cards_vector`, I want to add the map to cards_map with key `card-n`, where n increments from 1 to `count(cards_vector)`. So, `cards-map` should return

```
{:card-1 {...}
 :card-2 {...}
 ...
 :card-n {...}}
```

Comment: Why bother with `:card-X` as keys - what else would be in `card-maps`? Also please add the code you have tried and how it failed so we can improve on it. Right now it's not clear, what you are struggling with (hints: `map-indexed`, `reset!`, `keyword`)

Comment: you can also use `(zipmap (map #(keyword (str "card-" (inc %))) (range)) data)`

Answer (score 2):

I propose this snippet:

```clj
(->> [{:a 1} {:b 2}]
     (map-indexed (fn [idx value] [(keyword (str "card-" idx)) value]))
     (into {}))
;; => {:card-0 {:a 1}, :card-1 {:b 2}}
```

But I agree with the comment of [cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick). Choosing a key with the shape `:card-X` doesn't seem to be really practical. But you can do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, closer to imperative programming but maybe less efficient than map-indexed:

`(into {} (for [k (range (count @cards_map))] [(keyword (str "card-" k)) (nth @cards_map k)]))`